# Dynamic row with JSON and PHP won't output data

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, json

I'm having trouble generating dynamic table rows with data in them. The data is being fetched from a db with a PHP script, and the client side is being handled with jQuery.
This code just displays empty table rows without the data values.

Can someone check what exactly is wrong with it?

The js script:

```
if(odabrano === "g"){

$.getJSON("nutritional_value.php?value=" + encodeURI(value), function (data) {
var ttr = $("<tr />");    
$.each(data, function(k, v){
    $("<td />").text(v * (parseFloat(uneseno, 10) / 100)).appendTo(ttr);
});
$("#tejbl").append(ttr);
});

}
```

The PHP script:

```
<?php

include 'connect.php';

//$value = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$value = $_GET['value'];


$query = mysql_query("SELECT NAME, FAT, FIBER, SUGARS FROM ccm WHERE NAME LIKE '$value%'");
while( $run = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
/*     $name = $run['NAME'];
    $fat = $run['FAT'];
    $fiber = $run['FIBER'];
    $sugars = $run['SUGARS'];  */

            $results = array();
            $results["name"]=$run['NAME'];
            $results["fat"]=$run['FAT'];
            $results["fiber"]=$run['FIBER'];
            $results["sugars"]=$run['SUGARS'];
            //Send it to the client in json format:
            echo(json_encode($results));

}


?>
```

Comment: Is your AJAX call retrieving anything, or is the problem in the displaying of the data?

Comment: There is a problem with retrieving the data, I get empty rows..

Comment: try `alert(data.name)` and see if you get the value right.

Comment: @Spokey I dont even get an alert :S

Comment: @Filkatron can you post the JSON ? and also add `.fail()` and see if it works.

Comment: @Spokey omg I'm sorry I don't even have a JSON, do I really need to have it? I'm new to all of this. As I see when you create a JSON you're kinda making a small db. (this is probably wrong, as my knowledge is very limited) I'm kinda confused now

Comment: @Filkatron well you are using `$.getJSON`. jQuery tests the result and if it's invalid it won't work well.

Comment: What do you get when you load the PHP script directly in a browser instead of calling it via ajax?

Comment: @Spokey Well I thought it got it from the nutritional_value.php with the
    echo(json_encode($results));

Comment: @Filkatron if you to the the url `nutritional_value.php?value=100` in your browser what do you get?

Comment: @jcsanyi I get this:
Notice: Undefined index: value in C:\xampp\htdocs\tust\nutritional_value.php on line 6
So this is the problem I guess: $value = $_GET['value'];

Comment: What if you load it in a browser as nutritional_value.php?value={something} ? I don't know what a valid value is... where does your javascript get the value from?

Comment: @Spokey I get only this: []

Comment: @jcsanyi it gets it from a link: var value = $('a').text();
I get: []
For the value banana(which is in the database)

Comment: So what happens if you run this query manually against the database?

Comment: SELECT NAME, FAT, FIBER, SUGARS FROM ccm WHERE NAME LIKE 'banana%'

Comment: when I changed the LIKE 'banana%' and ran nutritional_value.php?value={banana} I got: Notice: Undefined variable: banana in C:\xampp\htdocs\tust\nutritional_value.php on line 11
And when I ran just nutritional_value.php I got:Notice: Undefined index: value in C:\xampp\htdocs\tust\nutritional_value.php on line 8

Comment: How about nutritional_value.php?value=banana ?

Comment: I get the values from the database:

{"name":"banana","fat":"0.3389","fiber":"2.62","sugars":"12.2"}

Comment: Can you add some debugging alert() values to the javascript? Maybe alert(data['fat']) and alert(uneseno) inside the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're not passing a value for the javascript variable `value`

What happens if you change the getJSON javascript line to this:

```
$.getJSON("nutritional_value.php?value=banana",function(data){
```

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the problem.
Nothing happens when I do this. Same as before. only a row with empty <td>'s

Comment: No, that indicates this isn't the problem. We saw that nutritional_value.php?value=banana returns correct values, so if you're using a URL that gives correct values and still seeing blank TDs, it's something else

Comment: Omg I just tried it again but with the js code below and I got the <td>'s filled up with the right values :D

Only the name is NaN instead of banana

Comment: First, you're not properly setting the `value` variable in javascript before using it to generate the URL.
Second, the javascript isn't properly parsing the data returned, and the below javascript helps.

Comment: So how do I fix these problems?

Comment: How is the javascript supposed to know what value to use? Where do you expect it to get "banana" from? Is it entered by the user? part of the URL?

Comment: there is a first search
You enter banana
it gives out a link with the text banana and the js takes that text and sets it to the variable value

Comment: That part's not working. You can confirm by putting alert(value) right before the getJSON call.

Comment: I can't help you more without seeing what's supposed to be setting the value variable.

Comment: It's working. I put it before getJSON and I got alert with the text from the link. So the value is set properly.

Comment: omg jcsanyi it works !
It finaly outputs the values. 
Thank you so much for your patience and time.

Now the only thing is it won't output the name it prints out NaN. But I'll figure it.

Comment: Try this line:
$("<td />").text(k=='name' ? v : v * (parseFloat(uneseno, 10) / 100)).appendTo(ttr);

Comment: Perfect :)
Thank you once again!

Comment: I just realized the code below, it outputs the tr for all the searches I made and the current one. So it adds a lot of rows, if I search for an item 3 times it will add 6 rows in the table.
Don't know how to change this.
I think the problem is the 
$.each(data, function(k, v){
line

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

```
$.getJSON("nutritional_value.php?value=" + encodeURI(value), function (data) {
    var ttr = $("<tr />");    
    $.each(data, function(k, v){
        $("<td />").text(v * (parseFloat(uneseno, 10) / 100)).appendTo(ttr);
    });
    $("#tejbl").append(ttr);
});
```

A suggestion to the PHP file.

```
<?php

include 'connect.php';

if(isset($_GET['value'])){

$value = $_GET['value'];


$query = mysql_query("SELECT NAME, FAT, FIBER, SUGARS FROM ccm WHERE NAME LIKE '$value%'");

$results = array();

    while($run = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

       $results["name"] = $run['NAME'];
       $results["fat"] = $run['FAT'];
       $results["fiber"] = $run['FIBER'];
       $results["sugars"] = $run['SUGARS'];

    }

    echo json_encode($results);

}

?>
```

Comment: Same thing happens. No values in the <td>'s, just empty rows :s

Comment: Tried it, still the same. :S